# What is this Ramsey problem?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, random-graphs, ramsey-theory

Given positive integers, $n,m,r$, define $R((n,m);r)$ to be the least $N$ such that for any $r$-coloring $C:E(K_N)\to \{1,\dots,r\}$, there is some monochromatic subgraph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges.

Surely this problem has been studied before. Is there a good reference for it, or any interesting conjectures here?

**Edit:**

I was aware of the fact that when $m\le \frac{1}{r}\binom{n}{2}$ that $R((n,m);r) = n$.

However, the problem still seems very interesting to me. For example, what can we say about the shape of $R((n,(1/2+\epsilon)\binom{n}{2});2)$? This should be at most (roughly) $n2^{2\epsilon n}$ by a modification of [the Erdos-Szekeres argument for finding cliques](http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1935__2__463_0.pdf). But if I use a random coloring, then I think we only get a lower bound of $2^{\Omega(\epsilon^2 n)}$ by appealing to a Chernoff bound.

Comment: One simple comment is that if $m\leq \frac{1}{r}\binom{n}{2}$, then $R((n,m);r)=n$ (by taking the majority color class).  So the parameter is only interesting for "dense" graphs.

Comment: I think you might want to add some restrictions (such as connected subgraph) otherwise by pigeon-hole principle isn't this just $$ N = \max \left[ \min\left\{ k,\ m\leq \left\lceil \frac{1}{r}\binom{k}{2}\right\rceil \right\} ,n \right]$$ ?

Answer (score 4):

A good reference is [Radziszowski's article Small Ramsey Numbers](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1/pdf), which gets updated as new results are proven. In particular, this refers to basically all known Ramsey style results. The ones you're interested in have the notation $R(G_1,G_2,\dots,G_r)$, where we're $r$-coloring the edges of a $K_N$, looking to avoid a monochromatic $G_j$. Your $G$'s run through all possible graphs with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. These questions are answered for small $n$, or for $G_j$ of certain types (e.g., a complete graph, complete graph minus an edge, tree, cycle, cube, fan, wheel, book, star, path). For general $n,m,r$ the question is open, but this article links to dozens of others that deal with various special cases.